# Is there any other way to solve absolute value inequalities than to make cases?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

To solve an absolute value inequality, we can do two things right: make a bunch of cases or graph the thing.

But for a big inequality like: $$||x|^2 - 8|x| + 15 + |x + 1| - |2x - 5| + |x|| < 2$$ we will have to make a lot of cases. I was thinking if there was a faster way of solving these big inequalities?

Comment: You have three "inner" absolutes which are $x,x+1,2x-5$ and then the "outer" one.  This doesn't seem like too many cases.

Comment: @abiessu what about |x|^2 - 8|x| + 15? Would I not have to consider -5,-3,3,5?

Comment: No, @Potato because it is (|x|-5)(|x|-3) and not |x-5||x-3|.

Comment: For students relatively new to these types of problems, I definitely recommend cases.  As another comment has indicated, there are only $3$ critical points, so you are only breaking the number line into $4$ regions.  Once you set up the cases, the corresponding analysis in each case will approach being quick and easy.